# Parity INK contract error when declaring multiple stroage

Tags: ink

I have implemented ink contract which use to create token, as shown below, I have two struct with declare
`#[ink(storage)]`, I am getting below error, How to solve it.

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

#[ink::contract]
mod my_token {
    use super::*;

    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct MyToken {
    
    }
    impl MyToken {
        // here are some implementation
    }
 

  
    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct TokenValue {
        Value: u128,
    }
    
    impl Default for TokenValue {
        fn default() -> Self {
            TokenValue { value: 0 }
        }
    }
    impl TokenValue {
     // here are some implementation
    }
}
```

ERROR:

```
error: encountered multiple ink! storage structs, expected exactly one
    |
4   | / mod my_token {
5   | |     use super::*;
6   | |
7   | |     #[ink(storage)]
...   |
304 | |     }
305 | | }
    | |_^

error: ink! storage struct here
  
   |
8  | /     pub struct MyToken {
9  | |  
18 | |     }
   | |_____^

error: ink! storage struct here
    |
197 | /     pub struct TokenValue {
198 | |         Value: u128,
199 | |     }
    | |_____^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ink! contract is only allowed and required to have exactly one #[ink(storage)] struct ([ref](https://use.ink/basics/contract-template))

Comment: Incase if I want use multiple struct value to be  stored , How to achieve it ?

Comment: I suggest going through the [docs](https://use.ink/) first and raise a more specific question when you have it :). In addition, check this answer as "answered" if it did.

Comment: Inside docs look in this [link](https://use.ink/datastructures/custom-datastructure#using-custom-types-on-storage)